# Set style if not done already

Tags: javascript, jquery

If scrollTop has a certain value I want to set a style. If the style is set already the code should not run again. How can I implement that in a efficient way?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop >= winH) { 
        $('box').css({ 'position':'absolute', 'top': winH });
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure you're not reinventing position:fixed ?

Comment: position:fixed is good, but not suitable for all situations. e.g. Jira uses something similar for topbars which change from static to fixed: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use a variable to set to true when you apply that style, e.g.

```
var scrolled = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (!scrolled && scrollTop >= winH) { 
    scrolled = true;
    $('box').css({'position':'absolute','top': winH});
  }
});
```

or, even better, you may unbind the handler, e.g.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop >= winH) { 
    $('box').css({'position':'absolute','top': winH});
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
});
```

---

Anyway

1) You may use `position: fixed` or, on newer browser, also `position: sticky` (if this is the case, I don't know what you're trying to achieve)

2) Is not a good idea to continuosly call an handler on `scroll` event. Consider to use a timeout instead (see http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) to regularly check your scrolltop position